# Parsing url and routing issues

Tags: php, url

```
www.foo.com/Base/index.php/controller/method/
```

This is my url, I need to get only "controller/method" part out of it - is there any elegant way to achieve this?

```
parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH)
```

This would be great, but it returns the whole "Base/index.php/controller/method" part.

Comment: `explode` the result ?

Comment: Exploding, removing...it's not really that elegant for me :P

Comment: @user2252786 Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 3):

```
$url = "http://www.foo.com/Base/index.php/controller/method/";
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);

$parts = explode("/", $path);
$index = array_search("index.php", $parts);

$controller = $parts[$index+1];
$method     = $parts[$index+2];
```

You did not provide any additional information about url format. But as example, you may use regular expressions with [preg_match()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
$url = "http://www.foo.com/Base/index.php/controller/method/";
preg_match ("/^.*Base\/index.php\/([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)\/([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)\/?/", $url, $data);
$controller = $data[1];
$method     = $data[2];
```